# Issues with internationalization in .net

Tags: .net, localization, formatting

I am working on an application that is being used globally by  users from different countries. We are recently facing an issue with the application when run in 'Portuguese' locale.

The actual issue we face is  that the 'Cost' field doesn't display the '.' separator. But, from my analysis I  understand that ',' is the separator that's being used in 'Portuguese'. But, that;s not displayed either.

For e.g. the value of **3425.25** is being displayed as **342525**. We retrieve this value from DB which returns 3425.25. The same works alright for other languages.

Please help.

Comment: Please post the code you use to display the value.

Comment: Hi @Sarah Elan , I am using the  below  expression to set the  value of a cost field in the  rdlc. I am  expecting a value of  20,00. But, it  displays  20.00.  Expression Used -  FormatCurrency(Fields!ShpmentBaseCst.Value,2,-2,0,-2). I tried using Format(Fields!ShpmentBaseCst.Value, "c") too. But it  displays 20,000.00. To give you more info, The value that's being fetched from DB is 20.0000 Note: I am setting the cultureInfo in my StartUp.vb

Answer (score 0):

Just for displaying convert the value to toString() , then replace dot(,) with , (comma).

Ex:

```
    float floatvalue= 342.23
    string stringValue = floatvalue.toString();
    string resut =  stringValue.Replace('.',',);
```

then display output, when you are calculating just calculate using floatvalue

Comment: Hi @user3730250, Thanks for the reply. I don't think that i can  do this since my  problem is  with RDLC files. Am not sure how  to check for the  CurrentCulture in an RDLC file and  to do the  rest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the culture info, then apply the correct formatting for that culture.

For example, to get the current culture (in VB.Net):

```
Private Function GetCurrentCulture() As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
    Return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
End Function
```

Gets which culture you are using. And then to apply the number format for the currency, you can use the cultureinfo.numberformat property described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It is also worthwhile looking at the jQuery globalization plugin, which is very useful in applying globalization with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Yupieeeee! I found out the solution for my issue.

The issue was with my conversion. We fetch value from DB and try to convert them to the desired type and populate the response object.

The value is returned as a 'String' from DB. For e.g. "20.0000". 
In case of Portuguese, the '**NumberFormatInfo**' has the '**DecimalSeparator**' as "**,**". 
But, my value doesn't have a comma separator in its value and hence the conversion to decimal functions wrongly. It converted it to a value of '**200000D**', which is wrong. Now, it works fine after i changed the '**DecimalSeparator**' to "**.**" even for Portuguese and passed the **IFormatInfo** as one of  the param to **ConvertType** method..